# How can I edit the default behavior of jetstream's email verification on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I recently created a Laravel project with Jetstream and Livewire implemented and I want change the behavior of the email verification feature after login or registration such that rather than redirecting the user to the '/email/verify' page, I want the user to be redirected to the '/dashboard' page with a modal prompting the user to verify their email, i.e. I want the user to perform the verification of their email in a modal on the dashboard, How can I do that?

Comment: not sure with Jetstream but in Laravel 8 breeze, you will either edit the `RouteServiceProdivder`'s `public const HOME = '/home';` to `/dashboard` if you are using this value.

Comment: or in `LoginController@login`' then change the `return` part to whatever route you want. From here you can check how to use db values in blade or something

Comment: Check how the auth is handled in Jetstream

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth you should post your comment as the answer